# Bing map control - eventtocommand mouseleftbuttonup

Tags: windows-phone-7, mvvm-light, bing-maps

Small question, I added a pushpin to a bing maps control on my windows phone 7 view.
I have an EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonUp" that maps to a command on my viewmodel.
So when I click that pushpin, my code in the viewmodel is triggered.

But when I also add EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonUp" to the bing map itself, only that code will be triggerd and the code specific for the pushpin click is ignored.

So any tips on how to add seperate eventriggers for the bing maps parent control and it's map item controls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't have a Tap event handler for the Map itself, if you're handling tap-events on the PushPins.

The problem is related to the bubbling of events, which you can't do a awful lot about. Also, why would you want to have a tap-event on the map in the first place?

Comment: Well... the app will show several pushpins, and on 'tap' of a pushpin show an overlay on top of the map. Tapping the map itself will clear the overlay... You can see my current version here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FamuF5S_XXo but I do a 'dirty' hack to get this working. Was looking for 'other' solutions.

Comment: If you look at the youtube video, you'll see that when I click from pushpin A on pushpin B the overlay will briefly clear and reappear... that is because of the Map also getting the tap event.

Comment: I do something like it in one of my apps. But I don't have the problems you describe. You could post the event handling code for the map and pushpin ?

Comment: The mapclick is link with EventToCommand to: `this.MapClickCommand = new RelayCommand(() => this.StationPopupVisible = Visibility.Collapsed);` The pushpin command has following code `this.StationPopupVisible = Visibility.Visible;` `this.SelectedStation = (from Station station in this.POIList
                                    where station.station_id == id
                                    select station).FirstOrDefault();`

Comment: Just for reference, it seems bubbling effect is something you can't do much about like Claus states... so my current solution stays in place.

Comment: Once you upgrade to Mango there's a `Tap` event available =) Also, changing the visibility is the responsibility of the view, not the viewmodel. So I would handle it purely in the view code.